# How to use scheduled run datetime as a variable in Azure YAML pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

I built an Azure YAML pipeline to generate daily prediction for the customer. In the pipeline, I use schedule trigger to achieve daily run, and I also use the date as an variable in the pipeline and as input to the python script running in the pipeline. A few weeks ago, there is infrastructure change in our system which failed my pipeline so I paused my pipeline runs and wait for the infrastructure to be repaired. Now the infrasture is repaired and I want to re-run all the scheduled runs in the last few weeks. This is where I ran into trouble. When I built the pipeline, I used `pipeline.startTime` to capture the date. This is OK if the pipeline is run on time on the scheduled date. However, now I am doing a delayed run, using `pipeline.startTime` is incorrect, because I don't want to run the pipeline for today, instead I want to pipeline to run as if the time is still in the last few weeks.

Is there a way to capture the orginally scheduled run datetime in the pipeline and use it as variable in the pipeline and as an input to my python script?

I noticed in the name of my pipeline, the originally scheduled run time is actually captured in a variable called `Date`. See below:

`name: Predict_$(SourceBranchName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Rev:r)`

However, I am not able to use it in the following tasks in the pipeline. I cannot `echo` it, and it seems not feeding into my python script correctly as an argument.